# New project in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy. I found the error when I create new project.

So please tell me How to create new project in scrapy.
I am trying as following-

```
scrapy start project
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What  is the version of Py and Scrapy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go to directory where you want to create project using-

```
cd path/to/directory
```

in the command prompt.
Then run the command-

```
scrapy startproject project_name
```

you are using space between start and project which is incorrect.